# Does connecting to same VPN mean connected to same network?

Tags: vpn, internet

Take this for example:

**Computer 1:**
*Internet 1* --------> *VPN1* -----------> *IP: 111.111.111.111 (for example)*

**Computer 2:** *Internet 2* --------> *VPN1* -----------> *IP: 111.111.111.111 (for example)*

The example that I tried to show above means I am connected to **different internet sources** but connected to the **same VPN** giving the same IP.

**My Question**
If I was to do something like *connect two phones via a game* because I have the same IP and VPN, will it be *classified* as the same connection or different?

*Hope this made sense...*

Comment: Where do the two phones come into play?  Via a game?   I am assuming you mean two IP phones? It seems like it would be the same connection, just not sure how phones play into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with a typical VPN you would join a LAN from a remote location and be part of that network. However if you're planning on using a commercial (or free) VPN service this might not be the case, clients connected to this service can't normally talk to each other and the VPN connection is more used for security or location spoofing.